# OpenGL Deferred Shading Pixelation

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, lighting, deferred-rendering

I'm working on a 3-pass deferred lighting system for a voxel game, however I am having problems with pixelated lighting and ambient occlusion.

The first stage renders the color, position and normal of each pixel on the screen into separate textures. This part works correctly:

[image: Base Rendering with no lighting]

The second shader calculates an ambient occlusion value for each pixel on the screen and renders that to a texture. This part doesn't work correctly and is pixelated:

[image: Base Rendering with Occlusion Applied]

Raw occlusion data:

[image: Raw Occlusion Data]

The third shader uses the color, position, normal and occlusion textures to render the game scene onto the screen. The lighting in this stage is also pixelated:

[image: Lighting]

The SSAO (2nd pass) fragment shader comes from the www.LearnOpenGL.com tutorial for Screen Space Ambient Occlusion:

```
out float FragColor;

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D gPosition; // World space position
layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2D gNormal; // Normalised normal values
layout (binding = 2) uniform sampler2D texNoise;

uniform vec3 samples[64]; // 64 random precalculated vectors (-0.1 to 0.1 magnitude)
uniform mat4 projection;

float kernelSize = 64;
float radius = 1.5;

in vec2 TexCoords;

const vec2 noiseScale = vec2(1600.0/4.0, 900.0/4.0);

void main()
{
    vec4 n = texture(gNormal, TexCoords);

    // The alpha value of the normal is used to determine whether to apply SSAO to this pixel
    if (int(n.a) > 0)
    {
        vec3 normal = normalize(n.rgb);
        vec3 fragPos = texture(gPosition, TexCoords).xyz;
        vec3 randomVec = normalize(texture(texNoise, TexCoords * noiseScale).xyz);

        // Some maths. I don't understand this bit, it's from www.learnopengl.com
        vec3 tangent = normalize(randomVec - normal * dot(randomVec, normal));
        vec3 bitangent = cross(normal, tangent);
        mat3 TBN = mat3(tangent, bitangent, normal);

        float occlusion = 0.0;

        // Test 64 points around the pixel
        for (int i = 0; i < kernelSize; i++)
        {
            vec3 sam = fragPos + TBN * samples[i] * radius;

            vec4 offset = projection * vec4(sam, 1.0);
            offset.xyz = (offset.xyz / offset.w) * 0.5 + 0.5;

            // If the normal's are different, increase the occlusion value
            float l = length(normal - texture(gNormal, offset.xy).rgb);
            occlusion += l * 0.3;
        }

        occlusion = 1 - (occlusion / kernelSize);
        FragColor = occlusion;
    }
}
```

The lighting and final fragment shader:

```
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 texCoords;

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D gColor; // Colour of each pixel
layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2D gPosition; // World-space position of each pixel
layout (binding = 2) uniform sampler2D gNormal; // Normalised normal of each pixel
layout (binding = 3) uniform sampler2D gSSAO; // Red channel contains occlusion value of each pixel

// Each of these textures are 300 wide and 2 tall.
// The first row contains light positions. The second row contains light colours.

uniform sampler2D playerLightData; // Directional lights
uniform sampler2D mapLightData; // Spherical lights

uniform float worldBrightness;

// Amount of player and map lights
uniform float playerLights;
uniform float mapLights;

void main()
{
    vec4 n = texture(gNormal, texCoords);

    // BlockData: a = 4
    // ModelData: a = 2
    // SkyboxData: a = 0;

    // Don't do lighting calculations on the skybox
    if (int(n.a) > 0)
    {
        vec3 Normal = n.rgb;
        vec3 FragPos = texture(gPosition, texCoords).rgb;
        vec3 Albedo = texture(gColor, texCoords).rgb;

        vec3 lighting = Albedo * worldBrightness * texture(gSSAO, texCoords).r;

        for (int i = 0; i < playerLights; i++)
        {
            vec3 pos = texelFetch(playerLightData, ivec2(i, 0), 0).rgb;

            vec3 direction = pos - FragPos;
            float l = length(direction);

            if (l < 40)
            {
                // Direction of the light to the position
                vec3 spotDir = normalize(direction);

                // Angle of the cone of the light
                float angle = dot(spotDir, -normalize(texelFetch(playerLightData, ivec2(i, 1), 0).rgb));

                // Crop the cone
                if (angle >= 0.95)
                {
                    float fade = (angle - 0.95) * 40;
                    lighting += (40.0 - l) / 40.0 * max(dot(Normal, spotDir), 0.0) * Albedo * fade;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mapLights; i++)
        {
            // Compare this pixel's position with the light's position
            vec3 difference = texelFetch(mapLightData, ivec2(i, 0), 0).rgb - FragPos;
            float l = length(difference);

            if (l < 7.0)
            {
                lighting += (7.0 - l) / 7.0 * max(dot(Normal, normalize(difference)), 0.0) * Albedo * texelFetch(mapLightData, ivec2(i, 1), 0).rgb;
            } 
        }

        FragColor = vec4(lighting, 1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        FragColor = vec4(texture(gColor, texCoords).rgb, 1.0);
    }
}
```

The size of each block face in the game is 1x1 (world space size). I have tried splitting these faces up into smaller triangles, as illustrated below, however there wasn't much visible difference.

[image: More Triangles per face]

My thoughts are:

- The resolution of angles between pixels and light sources are not
  high enough, causing the banding lighting effect
- I am not tessellating the triangles on the block faces enough.

How can I increase the resolution of the lighting and SSAO data to reduce these pixelated artifacts? Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have mipmapping enabled on your normal gBuffer? Since your occlusion samples deliberately jump around randomly, this can make it look to the `texture` function like you're trying to draw a texture from a long way away, meaning it should drop to a smaller mip level to reduce texture aliasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to get pixelated light when precision of gBuffer textures was low.
Use GL_RGB16F or GL_RGB32F as internal format for position.
Position can be reconstructed from depth texture like this, so no need to save position and waste space in gBuffer:

```
vec3 worldSpaceFromDepth(in float depth) {
    float z = depth * 2.0 - 1.0;

    vec4 clipSpacePosition = vec4(uv0 * 2.0 - 1.0, z, 1.0);
    vec4 direct = pc.projectionCameraMatInverse * clipSpacePosition;
    return direct.xyz / direct.w;
}
```

Here is my gBuffer setup:

```
_depthComponentTexture = new Texture(_width, _height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_NEAREST);        
_worldNormalSpecPower = new Texture(_width, _height, GL_RGBA16F, GL_RGBA, GL_NEAREST);
_albedoSpecularIntensity = new Texture(_width, _height, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA, GL_NEAREST);
_3viewNormalSSAOShaderless = new Texture(_width, _height, GL_RGBA16F, GL_RGBA, GL_NEAREST);
```

[image: deferred shading]

Comment: Thank you! Changing my position buffer's internal format from rgb16f to rgb32f fixed it instantly :)

Comment: Its also faster to reconstruct position from depth than having multiple 32f textures.